# had been released for a few days

Tags: perfect-constructions

Some predicates are incompatible with the perfect aspect. For example, "He has died for five years" is incorrect. What about the following? Are they okay or similarly incorrect? Note that (c) is in the past tense, intended for comparison purposes and modeled by analogy with "He went to New York for five weeks."

> a. On August 23, 2005, I saw a movie which had been released for a few days.

> b. The movie has been released for a few days.

> c. The movie was released for a few days.

Comment: "He has died" is fine, but it's unlikely it took five years for him to die.

Comment: While "*He had been dead for five years*" is quite natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) *had been released a few days before* or *had been [on release](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/on-general-release) for a few days*.

(b) *was released a few days ago* or *has been on release for a few days.*

(c) same as (a).

Comment: Do you find "He went to New York for five weeks" okay?

Comment: Perfectly OK, because _went_ can refer to the outward journey or the entire trip, depending on context.

Comment: Is "He has gone to New York for five weeks" okay too?

Comment: Yes, implying 'He intends to stay there for 5 weeks'.